# WiFi Adapter AX201 Ubuntu 20.10 dropping connection frequently

Tags: network-manager, dell, hardware, iwlwifi

I bought a dell g3 15 a couple of weeks ago, and with this machine, the wireless connection drops regularly, sometimes coming back quickly, sometimes asking another time to confirm the password.

My other devices don't have the problem.

with dmesg, I see

```
root@machine:~# dmesg | tail -15
[ 8233.789105] wlp0s20f3: associated
[ 8235.316578] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticated from 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[ 8235.426129] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee
[ 8235.430130] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (try 1/3)
[ 8235.453413] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[ 8235.458847] wlp0s20f3: associate with 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (try 1/3)
[ 8235.462778] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[ 8235.467597] wlp0s20f3: associated
[ 8249.169987] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticated from 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[ 8249.245887] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee
[ 8249.249177] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (try 1/3)
[ 8249.273760] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[ 8249.281098] wlp0s20f3: associate with 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (try 1/3)
[ 8249.286273] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 5c:7d:5e:ff:4c:ee (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[ 8249.289137] wlp0s20f3: associated
```

The system info I could gather

```
root@machine:~# lspci | grep Wi
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
```

```
root@machine:~# lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi               364544  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              782336  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

```
root@machine:~# iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"WLAN-4CEE84"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 5C:7D:5E:FF:4C:EE   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:7   Missed beacon:0
```

```
root@machine:~# lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 70:9c:d1:f1:d3:6c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-44-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.u ip=192.168.2.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6001b1c000-6001b1ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: 34:73:5a:b8:8e:02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:83104000-83104fff memory:83100000-83103fff
```

Does anyone know how to fix or debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar error to you on my new Dell XPS 15 (with the same wireless card).

It's definitely an Ubuntu issue as my Windows installation on the same laptop works fine, and other devices connect to the network with no problem.

I tried many options that I read on the internet, with no avail.

However after getting my router to split the 2.5GHz and 5GHz channels, I found that connecting to the 2.5GHz channel has no problems whatsoever.

I recommend trying that.

Comment: Works for me: I limited the wlan modi to 802.11a and 802.11n, and have not experienced the issue since. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Majolo's answer works really well, and I used it for a few weeks. However I have a few older devices that cannot find the 5GHz band, and did not connect to Wifi anymore.

As an alternative solution I chose a fixed BSSID in WLAN settings. This seems to fix the issue as well, and does not require router setup changes.

The attached image shows the config for ubuntu 20.10. (click on your WLAN router and  pick WIFI - settings).[image]