# Wi-Fi 6 AX201 frequently dropping connection on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

I have a new Dell XPS 15 that I've installed Ubuntu on, alongside Windows.

The wifi connection works, but frequently (between 5-20 mins) it will drop out and I need to turn the wifi on and off again to get it working.

The wifi works fine on Windows so it's not a strict hardware problem, and a wired connection works fine.

```
majolo-xps:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for max: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: dc:41:a9:fa:30:e3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u ip=192.168.0.89 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
```

```
majolo-xps:~/Downloads$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Home Wifi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: AC:F8:CC:1D:EC:29   
          Bit Rate=650 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:16   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-fa72099ecf25  no wireless extensions.
```

```
majolo-xps:~/Downloads$ lspci | grep Wi
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
```

```
majolo-xps:~/Downloads$ dmesg | tail -15
[65368.197357] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77
[65368.201488] wlp0s20f3: send auth to e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77 (try 1/3)
[65368.231396] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[65368.235353] wlp0s20f3: associate with e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77 (try 1/3)
[65368.237707] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
[65368.240347] wlp0s20f3: associated
[65368.242283] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77
[65386.639407] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP e4:c3:2a:eb:9f:77 for new auth to ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29
[65386.643317] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29
[65386.645504] wlp0s20f3: send auth to ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29 (try 1/3)
[65386.676981] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[65386.679521] wlp0s20f3: associate with ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29 (try 1/3)
[65386.698005] wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=1)
[65386.700932] wlp0s20f3: associated
[65386.751594] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by ac:f8:cc:1d:ec:29
```

```
Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic
```

If anyone can help me solve this or point me to the best way of debugging I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Using the 5.4 kernel often solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this problem (connecting to the 2.5GHz band of my router and not the 5GHz band solved it). More discussion here: [WiFi Adapter AX201 Ubuntu 20.10 dropping connection frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323482/wifi-adapter-ax201-ubuntu-20-10-dropping-connection-frequently/1326315?noredirect=1#comment2262210_1326315)